# Printing a list with node.next in another struct

Tags: c, pointers

So i've figure it out how to link the list but now i want to display it, how can i achieve this. I already started to making the code but this just isn't right. Any help?

```
typedef struct baseNode_s
{
    struct baseNode_s *proximo;
} baseNode;

typedef struct identificador_s
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} identificador;

typedef struct contaBancaria_s
{
    identificador id;
    int saldo;
    int credito;
    baseNode node;
} contaBancaria;

contaBancaria *contaP = NULL;

void lcontas() {
    contaBancaria *p;   
    printf("\n=================INICIOU A listagem\n");
    for(p=contaP; p->node.proximo != NULL; p->node = p->node.proximo){
        printf("\n%d - %d - %d %d %d", p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
    }
    free(p);
    printf("\nChegou ao fim da listagem\n");
}
```

Comment: Actually, how you are building the linked list looks just plain wrong to me.

Comment: `contaBancaria *contaP = NULL;` is an initialiser. After that `for(p=contaP; p->node.proximo != NULL; p->node = p->node.proximo){ ... }` attempts to dereference p. You cannot dereference a NULL pointer, it is intended to point to nothing.

Comment: `contaBancaria *contaP = NULL; is an initialiser.` Correct, but I think contaP is initialized elsewhere. Can you post the code where you initialize the contaP and construct the linked list?

Comment: I suppose the list is already built, here you are overwriting your nodes in the list `p->node = p->node.proximo`, so after  `lcontas` the list is ruined.

Comment: Ricardo, your way of implementing a linked list is wrong. You kind of have the idea, but you're not yet there. You have `contaP`, and you may print whatever is there (id, saldo, etc. - and by the way notice that in the code you posted `contaP` stays `NULL` and you are trying to dereference it) but since `node` is of type `baseNode` you don't have access to the `contaBancaria` structure that actually holds that pointer (at least not without some tricks).

Comment: @JoãoFernandes With these kind of questions you have to assume that `contaP` is already made into a ( correct) list, so the dereference is just fine.

Comment: that contaP is just the head of the list and is inicialized to NULL

Comment: As I said: if it is NULL, you cannot dereference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of achieving your goal is by having a structure with a pointer to an element (in your case, things of type `contaBancaria`) and a pointer to the next element in the list. It is simple but requires you to perform a cast every time you want to access what is pointed by `elem`, an inconvenience that is normally removed through specialization using macros (take a look at [SLIST](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/sys/queue.h?rev=1.30)), but in this case lets just cast :-)

```
typedef struct baseNode_s
{
    void *elem;
    struct baseNode_s *proximo;
} baseNode;

typedef struct identificador_s
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} identificador;

typedef struct contaBancaria_s
{
    identificador id;
    int saldo;
    int credito;
} contaBancaria;

baseNode *contaP = NULL;

void lcontas() {
    contaBancaria *p;
    /*
    I'm assuming assume that you are building the list
    here and that contaP will point to its head.
    */
    printf("\n=================INICIOU A listagem\n");
    /*
    I'm also assuming that the first node in the list is garbage.
    This simplifies things like inserting (no special case).
    */
    for (p = contaP->proximo; p != NULL; p = p->proximo) {
        contaBancaria *cb = (contaBancaria*) p->elem;
        printf("\n%d - %d - %d %d %d", cb->id.a, cb->id.b, cb->id.c, cb->saldo, cb->credito);
    }
    /*
    Free the list properly...
    */
    printf("\nChegou ao fim da listagem\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the data structure you have defined, you need a mechanism to recover the original pointer to `contaBancaria` from the pointer to the `baseNode` that the `contaBancaria` contains.

You can do that with a helper function that uses the [`offsetof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/offsetof) macro.

```
contaBancaria *base2conta (baseNode *base) {
    return base ? (void *)((char *)base - offsetof(contaBancaria, node)) : NULL;
}
```

Then when you iterate, you can convert the `proximo` to a `contaBancaria`.

```
for(p=contaP; p != NULL; p = base2conta(p->node.proximo)){
    printf("\n%d - %d - %d %d %d",
           p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
}
```

You should also not `free(p)` in your print function. `p` is being used to read the list, no new memory is being allocated to do that.